# Sort end word in array

Tags: python, arrays

I have array example is following:

```
array_store = ['01-42.0-19.5-100-26.25-46.94-D', '01-61.0-19.5-100-26.25-51.69-C', '36.0-1.0-100-25.0-40.5-D', '52.0-19.5-70-35.0-44.12-A']
```

I want to sort the array_store in ascending alphabetical order with: A, B, C, D, E, F,.... With the last character of the element in the array.

**Except:** I want to

```
array_store = ['52.0-19.5-70-35.0-44.12-A', '01-61.0-19.5-100-26.25-51.69-C', '01-42.0-19.5-100-26.25-46.94-D', '36.0-1.0-100-25.0-40.5-D']
```

I'm trying code, but don't success:

```
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(array_store))
mylist.sort()
```

Please help me and thank you so much!

Comment: Can you edit your example to use `array_store` please? It is not clear to me what `array_ranking_supplier` is or why you attempted to create a dictionary from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting can take a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) as an argument, which you can use to extract the last character.

```
array_store.sort(key=lambda s: s[-1])
```

Which performs a stable sort by the last character `s[-1]` of each string.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(sorted(array_store,key = lambda c:c[-1]))
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation to the code. While this exact code may solve the problem, it is hard to reuse it for similar problems or even find by some keywords. SO purpose is to learn during ask/answer process, that's why it will be much more valuable to provide guidance, *why* this should work as described.